# Syntax Error JQuery Scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Im getting Syntax error 0x800a139e while trying to add iframe to a window document. Window here is a pop up opened using window.open. This works perfectly fine with main window but sadly not with pop up. Can somebody help?

```
Obj = $('<iframe class="notify-osd alert ' + cssClassType + '"></iframe>', this.parentDocument).css({ display: 'none', "opacity": "0" });
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with syntax. Probably check `Obj` though. You might need a `var` if it's the first time declaring it. Dunno if any syntax checkers check on declaration, maybe yours is throwing it.

Comment: var is present. Issue seems to be related to context of jQuery